# Change duplicated column names after merging multiple tables in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, merge

I have merged 4 files into one.

```
df1:
ID   name    location   case     pass
1    John      NY       tax       Y
2    Jack      NJ       payment   N
3    John      CA       remote    Y
4    Rose      MA       income    Y
df2:
ID   name    location   case   pass
1    John      NY       car     N
2    Jack      NJ       train   Y
3    John      CA       car     Y
4    Rose      MA       bike    N
df3:
ID   name    location   case     pass
1    John      NY       spring    Y
2    Jack      NJ       spring    Y
3    John      CA       fall      Y
4    Rose      MA       winter    N
df4:
ID   name    location   case    pass
1    John      NY       red      N
2    Jack      NJ       green    N
3    John      CA       yellow   Y
4    Rose      MA       yellow   Y
```

Here is how I merged those tables.

```
dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=[ID,name,location]), dfs)
```

But the result is a bit hard to read. I need to convert those `case_x,case_y,pass_x,pass_y`  to a specific column name. Can I do this when merging the tables?

```
 ID   name    location     case_x  pass_x  case_y      pass_y   case_x      pass_x  case_y   pass_y
    1    John      NY       tax       Y      car       N        spring      Y       red      N
    2    Jack      NJ       payment   N      train     Y        spring      Y      green     N
    3    John      CA       remote    Y      car       Y        fall        Y      yellow    Y 
    4    Rose      MA       income    Y      bike      N        winter      N      yellow    Y
```

Here is my expected output,

```
ID   name    location  case_money  pass_money  case_trans   pass_trans   case_season      pass_season  case_color  pass_color
1    John      NY       tax       Y           car                N        spring                 Y       red      N 
2    Jack      NJ       payment   N           train              Y        spring                 Y      green     N
3    John      CA       remote    Y           car                Y        fall                   Y      yellow    Y 
4    Rose      MA       income    Y           bike               N        winter                 N      yellow    Y
```

Comment: There is suffix option in the `merge` function, however I don't know how this will work when dealing with multiple dataframes. I would (considering you know the output) use `.rename(columns={'case_x':'case_trans','case_y':'case_season','pass_x':'pass_trans','pass_y':'pass_season'})` after the `reduce`.

Comment: Thank you, @IvanLibedinsky It's a bit hard to just rename the columns. Because my job is to merge 20 tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `reduce` is still possible with `suffixes` option and list `pop`

```
suff = ['_trans', '_season', '_color']
dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['ID','name','location'], 
                                          suffixes=('', suff.pop(0))), dfs)

Out[1944]:
   ID  name location     case pass case_trans pass_trans case_season  \
0  1   John  NY       tax      Y    car        N          spring
1  2   Jack  NJ       payment  N    train      Y          spring
2  3   John  CA       remote   Y    car        Y          fall
3  4   Rose  MA       income   Y    bike       N          winter

  pass_season case_color pass_color
0  Y           red        N
1  Y           green      N
2  Y           yellow     Y
3  N           yellow     Y
```

**Note**: just be careful with the list `suff`. You need to re-initiate it before re-running the code.

---

If you want the first `case`, `pass` rename to `_money`, just chain additional `rename`

```
df_final = (reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['ID','name','location'], 
                                          suffixes=('', suff.pop(0))), dfs)
                 .rename({'case': 'case_money', 'pass': 'pass_money'}, axis=1))

Out[1951]:
   ID  name location case_money pass_money case_trans pass_trans case_season  \
0  1   John  NY       tax        Y          car        N          spring
1  2   Jack  NJ       payment    N          train      Y          spring
2  3   John  CA       remote     Y          car        Y          fall
3  4   Rose  MA       income     Y          bike       N          winter

  pass_season case_color pass_color
0  Y           red        N
1  Y           green      N
2  Y           yellow     Y
3  N           yellow     Y
```

Doing this way, you only need to rename the first set `case, pass`, all other sets of `case, pass` already got named by `suffixes` through `merge`

Answer (score 3):

My approach with `concat` and `pivot_table`:

```
names = ['money', 'trans', 'season', 'color']
dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4]

new_df = (pd.concat(d.assign(name=n) for n,d in zip(names, dfs))
            .pivot_table(index=['ID','location', 'location'],
                         columns='name',
                         values=['case','pass'],
                         aggfunc='first')
         )
new_df.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in new_df.columns]
```